# Writing an ArrayList with different variables to a .txt file

Tags: java, text, arraylist, io, printwriter

I am currently undergoing a project where I aim to write an `ArrayList` that holds different variables such as `String`, `Integer`, `ArrayList`, `Date` etc to a `txt` file.

How would I go about doing this? I tried using a `PrintWriter` and just doing `.toString()` but this just returned all the `ArrayList`s addresses, like `ArrayList@1d34gh`.

How do I get it to print out each separate entity?

This is my most recent code (after implementing an answer given here):

```
public void writeToFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    for (Tweet t : tweets) {
        if (t.getAuthor() instanceof String) { 
            pw.println("Tweet Author:   @" + t.getAuthor());
        }
        else if (t.getDate() instanceof Date) {
            pw.println("Tweet Date:   " + t.getDate()); 
        }
        else if (t.getTweetID() instanceof Long) {
            pw.println("Tweet ID:   " + String.valueOf(t.getTweetID())); 
        }
        else if (t.getTweetContent() instanceof String) {
            pw.println("Tweet Content:   " + t.getTweetContent()); 
        }
        else if (t.getLikes() instanceof int) {
            pw.println("No. of Likes:   " + t.getLikes()); 
        }
        else if (t.getRetweets() instanceof int) {
            pw.println("No. of Retweets:   " + t.getRetweets()); 
        }
        else if (t.getOriginalUser() instanceof String) {
            pw.println("Username of Original Username:   " + t.getOriginalUser()); 
        }
        else if (t.getRetweeters() instanceof ArrayList<String>) {
            for(String str : t.getRetweeters()){
            pw.write("Retweeter Usernames:  " + str); 
            }
        }

    pw.close();
}
```

I am trying to do the `int` variables, but they do not allow me to do `instanceOf` `int` or `Integer` and I am unsure why when likes & retweets are of `int`.

When I do it with `int`,  it returns the error: `Syntax error, insert "Dimensions" to complete ArrayType`

When I do instanceOf with `Integer`, it returns the error :`Incompatible conditional operand types int and Integer.`

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you please add some code?

Comment: You'd probably run into problems with nested lists etc. so maybe you could convert the list to JSON (use one of the mapper libraries) and write that JSON to a file. Alternatively have a look at libs like Apache Commons Lang etc. which should provide some nice utilities for printing arbitrary object hierarchies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this might be the way:

```
public void writeToFile(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException {
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream(fileName));
    for (T item : myArray) {
        if (item instanceof Character) { ... }
        else if (item instanceof Integer) { pw.println(Integer.toString(item)) }
        else if (item instanceof ArrayList<String>) { 
            for(String str: item) {
                pw.write(str);
            }
        }
       .
       .
       .
    }
        pw.close();
}
```

It takes work but **if you know the types of your members** you can check against them and write the appropriate conversion `toString()`. For most you can just use the [`String.valueOf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) method.

Comment: No problem glad it helped

Comment: what if I want to print an int variable, its saying Integer won't work and then if I use int it won't work either?

Comment: Sorry I don't really understand what you are asking... You can use this for every type, including integer. Integer is an easy case because you can easily use Integer.toString on it

Comment: like here else if (t.getLikes() instanceof int) {  won't work because it says it needs dimensions and (t.getLikes() instanceof Integer) doesn't work because they're incompatible

Comment: Please edit your question with your code and input + output. Hard to tell like this

Comment: i did, but it returns the error.. Incompatible conditional operand types int and Integer.

Comment: Try running t.getLikes().getClass()  instanceof Integer    please

Comment: returns the error "Can't invoke getClass() on the primitive type int"

Comment: I'll look at this soon I have to go do something else. I won't forget you tho (;

Comment: Hey please try t.getLikes().class and tell me if that works instead

Comment: says syntax error on token "class", identifier expected

Comment: I can't seem to solve it right now... If you return `Integer` from your `getLikes()` instead of `int` though it will be solved rather easily... Can you do that?

Comment: yeah that fixed it, didn't think that would work but it did! Brilliant thanks!

Comment: Hahaha I should have told you that from the beginning... Lolz my bad

Comment: thanks a lot man really appreciate your assistance! works a dream! just need to get it in its own method now

Answer (score 0):

you need to iterate your list in loop and put every value to your file. But before putting value to file make `String.valueOf(value)`

it would seems smth like this:

```
for (Object obj: list) {
     string = String.valueOf(obj);
   //put variable string in txt
    ...
}
```